# Matrix Factorization with user and item regularization VS Probabilistic Matrix Factorization

Tags: recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering, matrix-factorization

I'm working on collaborative filtering techniques and there's an approach called probabilistic matrix factorization ([paper-link](https://stackoverflow.com)).

I've been wondering about the difference between matrix factorization with l2 regularization and probabilistic matrix factorization.
Both seems to be the same thing, yet they're claimed not to be.

Thanks,